# Is Garbage Collection in java, specific to a JVM, what happens to other JVMs if an application in one JVM is leaking memory

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

I understand JVM is a standard process and each JVM has it's own heap, threads and each Java application uses an independent JVM.

I want to know if how does Garbage Collection in one JVM impact other JVMs in the machine?

My aim: Study GC STW pauses against an application I wrote.

Ques 1:

```
If an application in a JVM is leaking memory, will GC in that JVM stop threads
running in other JVMs too? My instinct says no, but I would like to confirm.
```

Ques 2:

```
How do I study the GC pauses of my application? Do I run a canary thread to 
measure the pause time and fire load to my application in the same JVM? How can 
I do so (in terms of number of threads)? I'd really appreciate an example.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common, but obscure problem you have is that by default your JVM will use all the CPUs in your system during a STW collection.  This means any other process running on the same box will slow down for the duration and possibly for a short time afterwards.

It has been suggested that you reduce the number of GC threads when running on a shared system.

Otherwise, if you have set sensible limits on heap size and not over committed your system, only JVM filling up shouldn't impact another.

> If an application in a JVM is leaking memory, will GC in that JVM stop threads
>   running in other JVMs too?

Only indirectly by using all the available CPU.

> How do I study the GC pauses of my application?

Print your GC logs and read them, or get a tool to read them.  Just studying them is often not as helpful as reducing you memory requirements and I suggest using a memory profiler, ideally a commercial one like YourKit.

It is much easier to tune a GC which is not heavily loaded. i.e. where you create less garbage in the first place.

> Do I run a canary thread to measure the pause time and fire load to my application in the same JVM?

You can do this.  There is a tool called [jHiccup](http://www.azulsystems.com/jHiccup) which does exactly that.  It makes pauses in your JVM more obvious.

> I'd really appreciate an example.

I would download the source and run it yourself.

Comment: However, that (STW using all CPU time) is a problem with any (parallelized) CPU-intense computation, or rather a problem with the fairness of the OS's process scheduling. You can run into it in the form of a runaway GC, but it's not specific to runaway GCs.

Comment: So to get a close enough estimate of the GC activity I should run a collection thread and my application in the same thread?

Comment: What is a runaway GC?

Comment: @user1071840 You can't run the collection thread in the same thread as the application.  You can enable GC logging and record detailed behaviour of your GC.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm sorry that was a typo, I meant run both the application and canary thread in same JVM

Comment: @user1071840 JHiccup offers a bet each way. You can run a thread in the JVM and it starts a thread in another JVM.  If they stop at the same time, it blames the system. If only one stops, it blames the JVM stopping.  However this is very approximate with 1 ms resolution, You can see much more low level jitter even without GCs http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/micro-jitter-busy-waiting-and-binding.html You can get delays of up to 5 ms with GCs on an otherwise idle machine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Thanks JHiccup looks good. Out of curiosity, for the approach where I'd have to write the canary thread a team-mate suggested that I should make the thread do some task and capture the duration the thread takes to complete that task. How would that be more helpful than measuring the period for which our canary thread over-slept? Also, this thread shouldn't contribute towards garbage collection itself right?

Comment: @user1071840 There is no need to run extra tasks as the system should be performing tasks of interest already and you can time those.  You are right that the monitoring should create a minimum of overhead of any kind or it distorts the results (including garbage)